# I want to add one hash to all the hashes in a string (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

So in my string, I have certain sections with hashes. For example, consider the string "#Hello, this is a sample string. This is another example of ###hashes".

I want to replace that with:
"##Hello, this is a sample string, This is another example of ####hashes".
(note that the number of hashes in each instance increased by one)

However, I'm not too sure how. I'd imagine it involved regular expressions, and I've searched a bit, but I'm not too sure what to do.

Can anyone help/lead me on the right path?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(#[^#])/', '#\1', $string);
```

Answer (score 4):

This works too:

```
preg_replace('/#+/', '#$0', $string);
```